# Help translating short poem for book

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, poetry

I'm writing a book right now about a cult. I've tried using google translate to take the initiation vows for the cult and put them in Latin, but it ends up terrible. If anyone could help me get this into Latin, and actually preserve the intended meaning, that would be amazing.

> All things that carry power, hear me now
>   Give me my virtue
>   Let me live according to my will
>   And give myself to those who have shown me the way
>   Let me teach others as I have been taught:
>   An inverted funnel system
>   And let them relinquish their power to me in the same way
>   Forever

P.S. This is probably too much to ask, but if there is a way to alter word use to make it rhyme you would literally be my favorite person in the world.

Comment: What does "an inverted funnel system" mean?

Comment: It's a funny way of saying pyramid scheme, that one could be literally translated to "Infundibulum inversum ratio" and that'd probably be fine

Comment: Welcome to the site! It's great that you are interested in Latin. The only thing is that translation requests are off topic here, unless you show what you have tried, and what parts you are not happy about. Something to work with. If you can add enough such information, the question will not be closed. Please don't take it personally, you couldn't have known, but this is the policy set by the community.

Answer (score 1):

omnes (or omnibus), qui vires gerunt, audite;
date mihi (meam) virtutem;
vivam de voluntate (or ambitione; or proposito; or auctoritate. In a recent Q on Will/ Willpower, "voluntas" won the prize.)

me (ipsum) do or dem (if it's still following "let me", from previous line, requiring pres. subj.) hos, qui moderati sunt;

doceam alios perinde doctus sum;

(you've-nailed-this-line);
relinquant mihi vires eodem modo;
in aeternum (or in perpetuo [tempore])

This will not be the best version, by any means; nor, is it written in the format of Latin verse. You will need contributions, from other colleagues, in order to achieve something worthy of publication.
Good luck with the book.